# Powershell Sending Emails via EWS the Message Body Format Messes Up

Tags: string, email, powershell, outlook, exchangewebservices

I have created a script that will run reports on a CSV file we get from CyberArk (password management) to see if passwords are older than a certain amount of days and send emails to those people who manage the accounts/assets.

However, when I send the emails the message body is formatted badly even when I think I formatted it correctly (outputs fine in POSH). So, maybe I am doing something wrong, or it is how the text is read in EWS. I will give some examples below of what I have tried. All these variables are read through an array and it loops through each record until all records are done.

Here-string code (tried with and without casting [string] & same results):

```
[string]$body = @"
Hello,

$notice

Target System: $targetSysEmail
Target Account: $targetAccEmail
Target: $targetEmail
Safe: $safeEmail
Last Password Change: $lastChangeEmail
Current Password Age in days: $currentAge
Days Overdue: $daysOverdueEmail
"@
```

Sample email:

```
Hello,

This account requires your attention right now:

Target System: some_oracle_server
Target Account: SOME_USER
Target: ROOT for Asset
Safe: MONEY
Last Password Change: 04/21/2015 00:00:00 Current Password Age in days: 97 Days Overdue: 7
```

As you can see the line breaks were not preserved.

Another example code I tried (tried with & w/o [String]):

```
[string]$body = "Hello, `n`n" + $notice + "`n`nTarget System: " + $targetSysEmail + "`nTarget Account: " + $targetAccEmail +
"`nTarget: " + $targetEmail + "`nSafe: " + $safeEmail + "`nLast Password Change Date: " + $lastChangeEmail + 
"`nCurrent Password Age: " + $currentAge + " days old" + "`nDue Date: " + $dueDateEmail + "`nDays Until Due: " + $daysUntilEmail
```

Example email:

```
Hello, 

This account requires your attention in the upcoming weeks:

Target System: some_cool_system
Target Account: account
Target: COOL_root
Safe: cashcash
Last Password Change Date: 05/06/2015 00:00:00 Current Password Age: 82 days old Due Date: 08/04/2015 00:00:00 Days Until Due: 8
```

All I want is each thing to be on a new line which is really not working. I tried outputting the body to a text file, which looks fine format-wise and then read it back in to try, but to no avail.

Full code to see if something is wrong:

```
#region Email Portion
if($email -eq 'YES')
{
#grab all the information from the new worksheet to then use for emailing the violators.
Write-Host 'Putting all the information into arrays'
$lastRow2 = $workSheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$lastChange = @()
$alias = @()
$safe = @()
$target = @()
$targetSystem = @()
$targetAccount = @()
$currentPWAge = @()
$daysOverdue = @()
$daysUntilDue = @()
$dueDate = @()
$level = @()
for ($loop = 2; $loop -le $lastRow2; $loop++)
{
$lastChange += $workSheet2.Range("A$loop").Value()
$alias += $workSheet2.Range("B$loop").Value()
$safe += $workSheet2.Range("D$loop").Value()
$target += $workSheet2.Range("E$loop").Value()
$targetSystem += $workSheet2.Range("G$loop").Value()
$targetAccount += $workSheet2.Range("H$loop").Value()
$currentPWAge += $workSheet2.Range("N$loop").Value()
$daysOverdue += $workSheet2.Range("O$loop").Value()
$daysUntilDue += $workSheet2.Range("P$loop").Value()
$dueDate += $workSheet2.Range("Q$loop").Value()
$level += $workSheet2.Range("R$loop").Value()
}

#use the previously collected info to formulate emails
#default email is my address, so change it to $email = Get-AdMailAddress (alias[$loop]) instead of $email = Get-AdMailAddress ("MY_ID") if running the real report
Write-Host 'Using the arrays to send out emails'
$n = '`n'
for ($g = 0; $g -le ($lastRow2 - 2); $g++)
{
$lastChangeEmail = $lastChange[$g]
$emailAd = Get-AdMailAddress ("MY_ID")
$safeEmail = $safe[$g]
$targetEmail = $target[$g]
$targetSysEmail = $targetSystem[$g]
$targetAccEmail = $targetAccount[$g]
$currentAge = [int]$currentPWAge[$g]
$daysOverdueEmail = $daysOverdue[$g]
$daysUntilEmail = $daysUntilDue[$g]
$dueDateEmail = $dueDate[$g]
$levelEmail = $level[$g]

if($levelEmail -eq "Red")
{
$subject = "URGENT: One Account Managed by You is in Violation of ___ 90 Day Password Life Policy"
$importance = 'High'
$notice = 'This account requires your attention right now:'
} 
elseif ($levelEmail -eq "Orange")
{
$subject = "URGENT: Password Change Required ASAP for this Account"
$importance = 'High'
$notice = 'This account requires your attention in the near future:'
} 
elseif ($levelEmail -eq "Yellow")
{
$subject = "Reminder: Password Change for this Account is Required Within a Week"
$importance = 'Normal'
$notice = 'This account requires your attention soon:'
} 
elseif ($levelEmail -eq "Green")
{
$subject = "Notification: Password Change for this Account is Required In the Next Two Weeks"
$importance = 'Low'
$notice = 'This account requires your attention in the upcoming weeks:'
}

if($importance -eq 'High')
{
[string]$body = @"
Hello,

$notice

Target System: $targetSysEmail
Target Account: $targetAccEmail
Target: $targetEmail
Safe: $safeEmail
Last Password Change: $lastChangeEmail
Current Password Age in days: $currentAge
Days Overdue: $daysOverdueEmail
"@
} 
elseif($importance -ne 'High')
{
[string]$body = "Hello, `n`n" + $notice + "`n`nTarget System: " + $targetSysEmail + "`nTarget Account: " + $targetAccEmail +
"`nTarget: " + $targetEmail + "`nSafe: " + $safeEmail + "`nLast Password Change Date: " + $lastChangeEmail + 
"`nCurrent Password Age: " + $currentAge + " days old" + "`nDue Date: " + $dueDateEmail + "`nDays Until Due: " + $daysUntilEmail
}

if ($importance -ne 'Normal')
{
Send-MailMessageViaEWS -To $emailAd -Subject $subject -body $body -Importance $importance
Sleep 1
} 
elseif ($importance -eq 'Normal')
{
Send-MailMessageViaEWS -To $emailAd -Subject $subject -body $body
Sleep 1
}
}
} #end first if
#endregion Email Portion
```

I have spent way too much time trying to figure it out and I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default body type in the EWS Managed API is HTML when you send a message, you haven't included the code for your Send-MailMessageViaEWS function but I would say if you haven't specifically told EWS your using a Text body that is your issue. (if you want to send a HTML Body then use

```
<BR>
```

instead of the

```
`r`n
```

the managed API won't convert these for you). But I would suggest you just use the Text body designator eg

```
$EmailMessage = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage -ArgumentList $service  
$EmailMessage.Subject = "Message Subject"  
#Add Recipients    
$EmailMessage.ToRecipients.Add("user@domain.com")  
$EmailMessage.Body = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MessageBody  
$EmailMessage.Body.BodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text  
$EmailMessage.Body.Text = "Body" 
$EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy()
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: We actually have it set up with -BodyAsHTML as a parameter, regardless I tried it with that and <br> and now the formatting is working well! Thank you so much!